# Error en en proceso almacenado de agregar

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hola que tal estoy intentando realizar un proceso almacenado en mi base de datos sql para agregar a mi tabla `Clientes`

Este es el proceso almacenado que estoy utilizando:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregarClientes(Codigo int, Nombre varchar(15), Apellido varchar(30), Direccion varchar(50), Fecha_Nacimiento Date, Tipo int, Foto varchar(55), Fecha_Ingreso Date, Ganancia double) 
INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (Nombre,Apellido,Direccion,Fecha_Nacimiento,Tipo,Foto,Fecha_Ingreso,Ganancia)
```

Y esta es la parte de como lo mando llamar:

```
call agregarClientes("ejemplo","ejemplo","Conocido","1991-03-30","1","ejemplo","1-04-2018","2500")
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error al momento de ejecutar la consulta:

## 1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE agregarClientes; expected 9, got 8

Mi campo id es autoincrementable y por como lo he utilizado usualmente no lo necesito ingresar en la parte de los paremetros al momento de llamarlo

Comment: Sólo tienes que sacarlo de los párametros que espera el procedimiento: CREATE PROCEDURE agregarClientes(Nombre varchar(15), Apellido varchar(30), Direccion varchar(50), Fecha_Nacimiento Date, Tipo int, Foto varchar(55), Fecha_Ingreso Date, Ganancia double)

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que sacarlo de los párametros que espera el procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregarClientes(Nombre varchar(15), Apellido varchar(30), Direccion varchar(50), Fecha_Nacimiento Date, Tipo int, Foto varchar(55), Fecha_Ingreso Date, Ganancia double).
```

Después:

```
call agregarClientes("ejemplo","ejemplo","Conocido","1991-03-30",1,"ejemplo","1-04-2018",2500)
```

Comment: Lo hice y ahora me muestra el siguiente error:

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura de tu tabla **empleados**?

Comment: Edité mi respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla empleados

Answer (score 0):

Debes modificar en tu procedimiento la sentencia insert y agregar los campos que vas a ingresar. Creo que es mejor que cambies los nombres de las variables de entrada del procedimiento para que no entre en conflicto con los nombres de los campos.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregarClientes(vNombre varchar(15), vApellido varchar(30), vDireccion varchar(50), vFecha_Nacimiento Date, vTipo int, vFoto varchar(55), vFecha_Ingreso Date, vGanancia double) 
INSERT INTO empleados 
(Nombre,Apellido,Direccion,Fecha_Nacimiento,Tipo,Foto,Fecha_Ingreso,Ganancia) 
VALUES (vNombre,vApellido,vDireccion,vFecha_Nacimiento,vTipo,vFoto,vFecha_Ingreso,vGanancia)
```